# Как вывести текст в Ruby с задержкой или по буквам?

Tags: ruby

Играюсь с чистым ruby и интересно каким образом можно вывести строку с текстом по буквам как будто печатает машинка или что бы строки выходили с некой задержкой. Подскажите как это делается или скажите каким образом лучше сформулировать запрос в гугл?

Answer (score 1):

Есть метод [`sleep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) для этого. Он принимает длительность задержки в секундах в качестве аргумента

```
'word'.each_char do |char|
  sleep 1  
  p char  
end
```